# What is the output of extractHOGFeatures function in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

I am currently doing a project and I require the use of some HOG features (histogram of oriented gradients). I used the following line:

`[features, visualization] = extractHOGFeatures(img);`

It looks like `features` is a vector of gradient intensities, while `visualization` is a struct that contains a little bit of information. But what I want to know is where do I get the actual angle values? Like how can I find out what percentage of gradients in this image fall between angles 0 and 40 degrees, for example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not really what HOG features are for. The HOG feature vector is a concatenation of gradient orientation histograms computed over overlapping blocks of pixels, which are, in turn, divided into cells. It is a good representation for training classifiers to recognize objects, but not a good way to determine what percentage of gradient orientations falls between 0 and 40 degrees. For that, you would be better off computing the gradient of the image yourself using `imgradient`, and thresholding on the orientation.

To get an intuitive feel for what your HOG feature vector means, you can use the visualization object:

```
plot(visualization);
```

Comment: Thanks Dima! That's what I ended up going with.